# Exploding URL Path On From Sub Directory Index.php Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble getting the main url from my sub directory. It has it's own application folder and index.php

```
http://localhost/project/admin/
```

I need my function below some how to remove `admin/` and only display `http://localhost/project/`

How am I able to explode it or something similar that will remove `admin/` and just show parent url.

`http://localhost/project/`

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {

    $catalog_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
    $catalog_url .= '://'. explode('/' . $catalog_url);
    $catalog_url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

} 
else{
    // Back Up Url
    $base_url = 'http://localhost/';
}

define('CATALOG_URL', $catalog_url);

unset($catalog_url);
```

Comment: You mean in the actual browser address bar?

Comment: yes what shows up in the address bar need it to not display admin/ I am just trying to get parent url. This function is on the sub directory index.php

Comment: You'll most likely need a `.htaccess` `RewriteRule` to achieve that.

Comment: It can be done with this I rather not touch the htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it for a while I had to do this

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {

    $catalog_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';    
    $catalog_url .= '://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . rtrim(rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 'admin'), '/.\\'). '/';

    } else {

    // Back Up Url
    $base_url = 'http://localhost/';

}

define('CATALOG_URL', $catalog_url);

unset($catalog_url);
```

Comment: As said before in previous comment no need change htaccess have got it working. Took me couple hours though to work it out.